# ToolBar with CustomView by Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, toolbar

I have a `Toolbar` with CustomView by **Fragment**, so When I set the `ToolBar` for **Fragment A** (the toolbar is rendered) and try to update it for **Fragment B I** don't get any update (not rendered)

**Code** :

```
private void setCustomToolBarForFragment() {
  Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

  // set CustomView
  View customToolBar =
    getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.toolbar_custom_view, null);
  ((TextView) customToolBar.findViewById(R.id.tool_bat_title)).setText("Favourites");
  ((ImageView) customToolBar.findViewById(R.id.icon_left)).setImageResource(0);
  ((ImageView) customToolBar.findViewById(R.id.icon_right)).setImageResource(0);

  toolbar.addView(customToolBar);
  toolbar.invalidate();       // restore toolbar
  ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the already present custom view in the Toolbar. `toolbar.removeAllViews()` before `toolbar.addView()`